# Redirect of web setup wizard - varnish

Tags: magento2, redirect, varnish

After installing varnish, I am unable to get to Web Setup Wizard. The browser spins for a while and then I end up on https://example.com:81/setup with an error that Chrome interprets as: `took too long to respond. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` which I think means a redirect loop.

My site is Apache and 100% SSL.

My Apache access_log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2019:20:23:42 +0000] "GET /hdadmin/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/setup/key/6c049d5d7c7cb9eb0c5a0babee49950449cc73c950d03cb7f74d967563bdf751/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[IP] - - [31/Dec/2019:20:23:42 +0000] "GET /hdadmin/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/setup/key/6c049d5d7c7cb9eb0c5a0babee49950449cc73c950d03cb7f74d967563bdf751/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2019:20:23:42 +0000] "GET /hdadmin/admin/backendapp/redirect/key/6c049d5d7c7cb9eb0c5a0babee49950449cc73c950d03cb7f74d967563bdf751/?app=setup HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[IP] - - [31/Dec/2019:20:23:42 +0000] "GET /hdadmin/admin/backendapp/redirect/key/6c049d5d7c7cb9eb0c5a0babee49950449cc73c950d03cb7f74d967563bdf751/?app=setup HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

My best guess is that there's something I'm missing in Varnish config that allows access to the setup wizard but I'm not very familiar with varnish setup.

Answer (score 0):

Can you setup magento first through websetup and then setup or enbale varnish on your server?

Comment: Magento is fully installed and configured, that's not the problem. I'd like to be able to get into setup wizard if I choose to, say, check the status of modules. I also know that I can manage modules via CLI, I'd just like to have the opportunity to use the frontend. Additionally, this just feels like a "bug" that I should address, it's not currently preventing me from doing anything.